# How to set $http headers

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework, csrf

```
    $http({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'withCredentials': true,
            'X-CSRFToken':$cookies.csrftoken
        },
        data: {
            "username":username,
            "password":password
        },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
    },
    function (response) {
    });
```

I send a http request just like this, and hope it has headers:

```
X-CSRFToken:3PTP6eV9rEDHvhBxOxRMOKhXb26zKpMOyBAMdhbaZAxnGxCxsISb5KUJOMCkfxO1
```

but get:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:withcredentials,x-csrftoken
```

My question is how to get the x-csrftoken out of Access-Control-Request-Headers

I have tried :

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
```